# Change html tag with same dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, html-parsing, phpexcel

I have a long table with different entries, some of which are marked as "xxx".
When the html code is generated, the row with the xxx looks like this(generated by a plugin):

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; border:2px solid #000000; width:504pt; height:29pt" colspan="12">xxx</td>
```

I want to change this to a textarea with same dimensions, so that it does not distort the table.

I have thought jQuery would do the job, but I can't figure out how exactly to extract the colspan, width or height, and set it to the new textarea. I have this code, which replaces all xxx instances to textareas, but they are all same sizes that distort the table format.

```
<script>
    var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/xxx/g,'<textarea></textarea>');
    $("body").html(replaced);
</script>
```

Any recommendation is appreciated.

PS: I'm using CakePHP 2.0 and use PHPExcel to change excel to html, and generate textareas wherever xxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always will replace "xxx", I don't understand why do you need to "extract" anything. If you play with the width attribute for a while, you'll get the exact pixels you need to not distort the table and hardcode it to the `<textarea style="width:XXpx">` definition.

Other thing you could do is to set the cols and rows attribute in the textarea definition

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/xxx/g,'<textarea cols="3" rows="1"></textarea>');
```

instead of the with, if the word is always 3 letters long, then use `cols="3"`.

If, however, I misinterpreted what you wanted to do, and you *need* to change the style and [attributes](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) dynamically, you can extract the colspan from the `<td>` with this

```
$("#the-td").attr("colspan");
```

You need to have the reference to the correct `<td>`, though. And for extracting [style](http://api.jquery.com/css/), the code is

```
$("#the-td").css("width");
```

Comment: Well, this may solve the case in some cases, but in my case I have a table that has different dimension boxes. So I just needed the textarea to fill the entire box. Setting cols=3 for example would not be appropriate in this case, but I'll accept the answer since it may work in some cases. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using the following code:

`var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/xxx/g,'<textarea style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height:3em; box-sizing: border-box; resize: none; display:block;"></textarea>');
$("body").html(replaced);`

This created tables wherever xxx that fit exactly the format of the outlining table. In the end, no complex data extraction was necessary.
My case was quite special, so I don't know if it'll help anyone, but hope it does.